# Is Django itself a backend?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have been reading into Python/Django but I was unable to find good info. I have learned that Django is a backend, but some people are saying that django itself runs on PostGreSQL?

So I need to learn both python/PostGreSQL? Or is DJANGO itself a backend?

Comment: Django is a web framework, part of which includes an ORM to interact with databases. It is entirely possible to have a website with Django that doesn't use a database though. Because of the ORM you can get started just by learning the ORM and that will free you from needing to know all of the SQL specifics. However it is good to know the database in more depth.

Comment: The definitions of frontend, middleware and backend strongly depend on the perspective.

Comment: The backend is still a huge piece of real estate with many components. Django's ORM lets you write "models" in python that represent database data and operations on that data. You can learn and use the ORM without ever writing your own SQL database access code. So, django usually front-ends a database but you don't necessarily have to learn the database to run django. That's kinda the point behind an ORM - its an (allegedly) easier way to access a database.

Answer (score 2):

Django is a python web framework. It can be used to create a backend. Django does not run on PostgreSQL, it can work with it as a database. But Django can work with many other databases as well, e.g. mysql, sqlite etc. If you want to learn web programming in python, then Django is a reasonble choice. However, there are many other popular alternatives to the Django web framework.

Comment: What are alternatives? Say I would like to create a social network like FB (basic ones) how would I do that?

Comment: You can use Flask and go through the Flask Megatutorial by Miguel Grinberg https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world In that tutorial he creates some sort of toy microblog. That might give an idea.